# To create Group Subscriptions. Do I need to create a subscriptions for each group on the organization to find change on the conversations

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

Let's say I have multiple groups and I want to get notified for any additional conversation on any of the groups so do I need to create subscriptions for each groupId endpoint. Or Is their way I create one subscription for change on the conversation of the groups on the organization.

Comment: What API specifically are you referring to and what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http Hi, Bill if you look at the link I added, it shows that I can create a subscription for a specific groups conversation by using v1.0/groups/id/conversations but I was wondering to create one subscription for all the groups in the organizations. Apologies for misunderstanding